# ¿Una oración con verbo infinitivo termina en punto?

Tags: gramática

Estoy desarrollando los objetivos de laboratorio, en donde los detallo, así:

- Hallar el flujo de calor del condensador
- Encontrar el valor del flujo másico
- Hallar el cop ideal del sistema

Mi duda radica en si se colocaría punto al final de cada objetivo.

Ayuda, por favor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En una enumeración, salvo que los ítems sean oraciones completas (en cuyo caso cada ítem se cierra con punto), se puede prescindir de un signo de puntuación o usar el que correspondería si los ítems conformaran una oración (la enumeración será algo así como la oración desglosada).

[Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/puntuacion-en-enumeraciones-con-vinetas-10941/) remite a [Wikipedia](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Enumeraci%C3%B3n), y aquí puede leerse:

> La puntuación al final de los elementos puede omitirse, sobre todo si son cortos, o puede ser la que correspondería si la lista estuviera integrada en el párrafo. También se puede optar por un signo concreto unificado en todas las listas de este tipo, que suele ser el punto y coma. De usarse puntuación, el último elemento cierra con punto.

La recomendación es la siguiente:

1. Si los infinitivos conforman una oración con la frase introductoria, separarlos con comas o puntos y coma, y cerrar el último con punto. Ejemplo:

Durante el periodo de rodaje conviene:

- cambiar el aceite cada 500 kilómetros;
- no frenar fuerte.

2. Si los infinitivos son equiparables a sustantivos, no usar signos de puntuación. Ejemplo:

Objetivos de laboratorio:

- Hallar el flujo de calor del condensador
- Encontrar el valor del flujo másico
- Hallar el cop ideal del sistema